# Как настроить логирование в 2 файла, в один сохранять информацию, в другой ошибки

Tags: java, логирование

Решаю задачу, в которой необходимо сделать два разных лога в папке logs проекта с помощью log4j2,  в один сохранять всю инфу обо всех запросов к программе, а во второй сохранять всю инфу об ошибках и исключениях.  Первый лог в который сохраняется информация я создал и он работает, подскажите как создать второй лог, в котором будут сохраняться ошибки?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    CustomerStorage executor = new CustomerStorage();
    logger = LogManager.getLogger();


    while (true) {
        try {
            String command = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = command.split("\\s+", 2);

            if (tokens[0].equals("add")) {
                executor.addCustomer(tokens[1]);
            } else if (tokens[0].equals("list")) {
                executor.listCustomers();
            } else if (tokens[0].equals("remove")) {
                executor.removeCustomer(tokens[1]);
            } else if (tokens[0].equals("count")) {
                System.out.println("There are " + executor.getCount() + " customers");
            } else if (tokens[0].equals("help")) {
                System.out.println(helpText);
            } else {
                System.out.println(COMMAND_ERROR);
            }
            logger.info( "Введена команда: " + command);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

рабочий файл log4j2.xml прикладываю ниже:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
    <File name="MyFile" fileName="logs/queries.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        <Filters>
            <ThresholdFilter level="warn" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />
        </Filters>
    </File>

</appenders>

<loggers>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="MyFile" level="info"/>
    </root>
</loggers>
```

Я так понимаю, что в нем мне нужно дописать код, но все попытки были безуспешные.

Comment: Если у тебя получилось с записью логов при штатном редими, то таким же макаром и err :)
А что ты пробовал? как ты делал?

Comment: добрый день, вот ниже написал ответ